# No connection between symbols

Tags: orcad

I've been working on a project of power converter in OrCAD software and I've come across such problem. Here is a piece of my schematic.

[image]

A Q1 transistor is in an SOIC-8 package. A Source pin is connected to 
I created a netlist and exported it to the OrCAD PCB Editor

My problem is as follows: Net name is OK, but why I don't see a logic connection between those two pads?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have nets disabled in your view - I don't see a 12 volt net either.

Comment: They are not disabled. I see other connections except for that transistor

Comment: In OrCAD you can selectively disable certain nets from being shown - it's somewhere in the area where you can apply different colours to different nets - have you tried that place to look for your problem?

Comment: I have checked almost every option and I didn't find anything related to it. I didn't even change any settings. I've just imported a netlist and a block of the power converter. Some pins features logical connections, some doesn't

Comment: Did you resolve this problem @Marco?